# how to delete a row using non primary key in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

This is my table with `id` as the primary key:

[image]

I want to delete the row based on `msisdn` column.

How can I do that?

Please suggest

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is: By writing a tool that first does a `select` using `allow filtering` to determine the primary key, then do the delete using the determined primary key.

The *actual* answer is: You don't, because what I just proposed would be terribly slow, put your cluster under a lot of stress, and generally reveal a misconception of how Cassandra data modeling works.

Cassandra data modeling is fundamentally different than SQL data modeling. In SQL, you have your primary keys, you normalize, and then you are pretty confident that you will be able to query and write most things with good performance. In Cassandra you model for your queries, and by queries, I mean anything that contains a `where`.

Assuming that you designed your table like this for a reason, what you could do is add a materialized view that adds `msisdn` to the primary key, turns it into the partitioning key, and turns `id` into a clustering column. That way, you could at least query efficiently without doing an `allow filtering`. You will still need two roundtrips, one for reading, one for deleting, but that cost may be acceptable. If it is not, you need to fundamentally redesign your table, keeping in mind that you will need to query by `msisdn`.

Comment: You're welcome. If you found it helpful, and consider your question answered, then please mark my answer as accepted, for other people to find it later.

Comment: Can I write a single query that deletes a row using materialized views?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not yet possible, no. You can only select on materialized views, not insert, update or delete.